# RabbitMQ - shovel plugin, accessing headers (properties) form Azure Service Bus

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rabbitmq, azureservicebus, bunny, rabbitmq-shovel

I need to implement rabbitMQ as sort of a middleware between Azure service bus and my rails app.
The message that is being sent uses headers which i also need to capture.

So, is there a way for shovel-plugin to also include headers with the shoveled payload?
Whenever i get the message from the shovel all the original headers are gone.

Also I am using Bunny as an amqp client in the app

Thanks!

EDIT:
Found this PR thanks to RabbitMQ slack:
https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/issues/2745

It seems that they are aware of the issue

I just created a Python middleware that handles appending headers to the payload and passes the data to RabbitMQ queue later on since it's literally 30 lines of code